# Configuration issue with apache derby in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, derby

In my spring boot based application, I have following in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I start the application, I get following error:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:
>       If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
>       If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

As dependency is there in pom, so classpath must have already it. So what can be the issue here?

Edit: I have not added any configuration related to apache derby in application.properties. I understand we don't need to do it for embedded databases. Or do we need?

Comment: Right click on the project and do update maven dependencies, as a first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

derby is expecting some datasource params like url for starting embedded server.

Try including jpa/hibernate config details in application.properties

Example:

```
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "create-drop" the database
# schema will be automatically created afresh for every start of application
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Just a change...create-drop must be replaced by update.